Android CameraX Unable to configure camera
I'm trying to create a simple camera app on android, I was following this this (medium.com) guide, but my preview doesn't load, I only get an empty screen.
Error in logcat:
Unable to configure camera Camera@1931e03[id=0]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Future[androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.futures.ListFuture@4319722] is not done within 5000 ms.
    at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.futures.Futures.lambda$makeTimeoutFuture$1(Futures.java:437)
    at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.futures.Futures$$ExternalSyntheticLambda7.call(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.HandlerScheduledExecutorService$HandlerScheduledFuture.run(HandlerScheduledExecutorService.java:243)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

My Main Activity looks like this:
package hu.automatx.android.connect4

import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import hu.automatx.android.connect4.ui.theme.Connect4Theme
import hu.automatx.android.connect4.vision.Camera

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val cameraPermissionRequest =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()){ isGranted ->
            if(isGranted){
                setCameraPreview()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            }
        }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        when(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            ) -> {
                setCameraPreview()
            } else -> {
                cameraPermissionRequest.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            }
        }
        enableEdgeToEdge()
    }
    
    private fun setCameraPreview(){
        setContent {
            Connect4Theme {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    Camera().CameraPreview()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

My Camera class looks like this:
package hu.automatx.android.connect4.vision

import android.content.Context
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalLifecycleOwner
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import kotlin.coroutines.resume
import kotlin.coroutines.suspendCoroutine

class Camera(){
    @Composable
    fun CameraPreview() {
        val lensFacing = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK
        val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
        val previewView = remember{
            PreviewView(context)
        }
        val cameraxSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(lensFacing).build()
        LaunchedEffect(lensFacing) {
            val cameraProvider = context.getCameraProvider()
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()
            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraxSelector, preview)
            preview.setSurfaceProvider { previewView.surfaceProvider }
        }
    }
    private suspend fun Context.getCameraProvider(): ProcessCameraProvider =
        suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this).also{ cameraProvider ->
                cameraProvider.addListener({
                    continuation.resume(cameraProvider.get())
                }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
            }
        }
}

I tried changing the CameraX libary versions back to an earlier version, but it didn't help.
What could be causing this error?

try this, i tried it and it worked : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52091715/setting-androidhardwareaccelerated-true-in-activity-or-in-application
